# Incompatible library version - cdo version requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0

Tags: macos, curl, cdo-climate

I'm trying to run CDO on my personal mac laptop. I had no issues with this up until recently when I installed nco - now I am getting the following error message when trying to run cdo:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/cdo Reason: Incompatible library version: cdo requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0 Abort trap: 6`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling curl but haven't had any luck with that.

Looking up the curl version yields:

`$ curl --version curl 7.21.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.3.0) libcurl/7.21.2 OpenSSL/1.0.0d zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.19 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp  Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz`

Which curl gives:

`$ which curl /opt/local/bin/curl`

How can I fix this?

Comment: how were you installing cdo originally?  By the way, you would have more luck if you used the correct cdo tag ;-)